# roo gem in Ruby

Tags: ruby, excel, ruby-roo

I am using 'roo' gem for reading and writing the excel sheets.
       How can I get the last column of each row in excel sheet using 'roo' gem in Ruby

Please give me some suggestion on this...

Comment: how do you write to excel file using roo gem?

Answer (score 0):

http://roo.rubyforge.org/

You can use a `for` with the method `last_column` as stated on the link above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
wb = Roo::Excelx.new 'somepath/somefile.xlsx'

1.upto(wb.last_row) do |row_index|
  last_column = wb.cell(row_index, wb.last_column)
end
```

Comment: Sorry just noticed how old this was.